Minimal permissions for EXCEL COM operations
I have a situation where i'm trying to limit the required permissions for an account that leverages Excel COM / process operations.
Worth to be noted, this account is an AD Managed Service Account.
Such operations include but not limited to the following :

Stopping excel process
get-process excel | stop-process -force

Instantiating Excel COM Object
$excel_input = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application


Current configuration results in the following errors respectively for each operation :

Cannot stop process "EXCEL (4960)" because of the following error: Access is denied.
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

I've included the account executing these operations in the following :

Component Services > DCOM Config > Excel Application > All Launch / Access / Configuration permissions positioned
Distributed COM Users Group
Users Group

Does somebody know what i'm missing here ?
